# BoxCollider2d как узнать сторону соприкосновения?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Есть Box Collider 2d, как узнать какой стороной он коснулся того или иного триггера ? К примеру если он коснулся верхом или правой стороной то происходил об определенное действие.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Способ.** Самый стародавний.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из рисунка квадратный объект-игрок скажет, что он столкнулся своей верхней частью, если его самая координата по Y будет больше, чем самая нижняя по коорината Y противника (или любого другого объекта).
Если самая нижняя координата по Y будет больше самой верхней Y противника - столкновение внизу.
Если самая левая координата по X будет меньше самой правой X противника - столкновение слева.
Если самая правая координата по X будет больше самой левой X противника - столкновение справа.

Т.е. делаете метод, который все это и будет рассчитывать и вернет в результате проверки с какой стороны он ударился/вошел в триггер.

**Памятка**. Следует помнить, что центр в юнити обычно в центре (а не вверху слева, как по стандарту). Поэтому рассчет крайней правой координаты по X будет примерно таков: `праваяСторона = координатыЦентраИгрока.x + ширинаИгрока/2`. Т.е. Отталкиваться от центра надо и от ширины игрока.

---

**2) Способ.** - Использовать *Physics2D*. Он, как минимум, включает несколько способов.

**2.1)** [OverlapCircle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html).

```
OverlapCircle(Vector2 point, float radius, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, float minDepth = -Mathf.Infinity, float maxDepth = Mathf.Infinity)
```

проверяет, пересекает ли объект с радиусом `radius` поверхность , у которого слой `layerMask`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Располагаем на объекте с каждой стороны по одному `EmptyObject`, которые, как раз, будут указывать на то, а с какой стороны что-то произошло.
Например

```
IsCollidingRight = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(rightObject.transform.position, 0.5f, enemyMask);
```

Где 
`rightObject.transform.position` - это тот самый `EmptyObject`, который находится справа у игрока.
`enemyMask` - это `LayerMask`, т.е. слой, с которым надо сверять пересечение. В данном случае она может быть объявлена как переменная в классе: `public LayerMask enemyMask;` и выбрана в выпадающем списке в инспекторе.

Либо объявление:

```
public int enemyLayer;
public int enemyMask;
```

И инициализировать так:

```
enemyLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy");
enemyMask = 1 << enemyLayer;    

IsCollidingRight = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(rightObject.transform.position, 0.5f, enemyMask); //IsCollidingRight = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(rightObject.transform.position, 0.5f, 1 << enemyLayer);
```

по вкусу

---

**2.2)** [LineCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Linecast.html) - рисует линию из объекта в указанном направлении и проверяет на пересечение с объектом определенного слоя, т.е. также маску можно использовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Располагаем на объекте с каждой стороны по одному (или несколько) `EmptyObject` (**чуть дальше сторон объекта!!**), которые, как раз, будут указывать на то, с какой стороны что-то произошло.

В скрипте проверяем на пересечение, например

```
IsCollidingRight = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, rightObject.transform.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy"));
```

Линия будет проводится из игрока к объекту, на стороне и если что-то определенного слоя попадется этой линии - то об этом будет сообщено

**2.3)** [RayCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) - Направляет луч из объекта в указанном направлении и проверяет на пересечение с объектом определенного слоя, т.е. также маску можно использовать.

Почти как `Linecast`, только пустышки (`EmptyObject`) теперь распологаем на самом объекте с каждой стороны по одному (или несколько), которые, как раз, будут указывать на то, с какой стороны что-то произошло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
IsCollidingRight = Physics2D.Raycast(rightObject.transform.position, Vector2.right, 1.5f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy"));
IsCollidingUp = Physics2D.Raycast(rightObject.transform.position, Vector2.up, 1.5f, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy"));

...
```

---

Итак, каким образом работать с лучами: пускать несколько, прикреплять их сразу на объекте или генерировать в коде (например занося в `List` и работать со списком) - решать уже вам и по вкусу.