# Как получить объект который вошел в триггер

Tags: c#, алгоритм, unity3d

Вот есть метод OnTriggerEnter(Collider), он качестве параметра принимает collider того объекта, например в триггер которого он вошел(ну то-есть просто collider в который вошел).
А как получить сам объект, который вошел в collider из самого объекта с триггером.
Надеюсь понятно написал.

> Я понимаю что триггер это тот же collider, просто не хотел повторяться.
>  Кратко: нужен не тригер получить из объекта, а объект который вошел в тригер нужно получить из самого тригера.

Comment: Вы будете смеяться, но `collider.gameObject`

Comment: @eastwing а если их несколько?

Comment: Кого несколько?

Comment: Объектов которые вошли в триггер

Comment: Значит несколько раз вызывается `OnTriggerEnter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нашел решение, получилось так:

```
foreach (Collider item in Physics.OverlapSphere (transform.position, Radius)) {
        if (item.attachedRigidbody && !item.isTrigger) {
        //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Вход в триггер - это событие, которое вызывает метод `OnTriggerEnter`. В каждом вызове обрабатывается один коллайдер, вошедший в триггер. Чтобы обратиться к его геймобджекту, нужно сделать так:

```
GameObject obj = collider.gameObject;
```

Если у вас в триггер одновременно могут войти несколько объектов, вы можете добавлять их в какой-нибудь список, и обрабатывать в цикле.

Comment: Я не вызываю OnTriggerEnter. У меня есть триггер, на нем например скрипт, и из этого скрипта мне нужно узнать вошло ли что либо в этот тригер.

Comment: @CGLike документацию нужно читать, уважаемый. Вам русским языком и объясняют...... для того, чтоб обработать этот самый вход, нужно в скрипте определить метод [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) который этот самый вход регистрирует..... Он получает [коллайдер объекта](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.html) в котором есть поле `gameObject` в котором как раз и лежит объект, который зашел в триггер

Comment: @CGLike Вообще, чтобы избегать недоразумений, лучше показывать какой-то свой код. Например, вы могли бы показать код обработки события. Потому что из вашего вопроса следует, что метод у вас уже определён

Comment: Да мне обратное нужно, я знаю как OnTriggerEnter работает, мне не нужно для объекта находить столкновение с тригером, мне нужно узнать ЧТО ВОШЛО В ТРИГЕР, ИЗ САМОГО ТРИГГЕРА, объект без тригеров влетает в тригер и мне из тригера нужно найти этот объект, зачем для тригера вызывать OnTriggerEnter если он сам триггер, и объект который влетает в него не имеет коллайдера

Comment: @CGLike А вам, извиняюсь, о чём пишут? Вы бы проверили, как оно работает, перед тем, как писать капсом на незнакомых людей

Comment: @CGLike Если второй объект не имеет коллайдера (о чем вы, кстати, не упомянули ни разу), то использование триггера не имеет смысла и вопрос сводится не к триггерам, а к  нахождению соприкосновения сторон объекта, который больше похож на расчет типа такого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532912/191482

Comment: Вот в вопросе написано "А как получить сам объект, который вошел в collider из самого объекта с триггером.
" а вы мне 'втираете' про OnTriggerEnter, как collider.gameObject может быть тем объектом который мне нужен, если  получается что я из этого объекта и вызываю скрипт?
Вы не поняли вопроса, допустим объект А вызывает OnTriggerEnter и получает collider объекта B. Так вот у меня есть объект B и из него я вызываю свой скрипт. В общем я узнал OverlapSphere, и видимо это то что нужно.

Comment: @CGLike `У меня есть триггер, на нем например скрипт, и из этого скрипта мне нужно узнать вошло ли что либо в этот тригер.`-это ведь **ваши** слова?Тогда ответ выше корректен...Либо вы не умеете мысли выражать правильно и у вас одно означает совсем другое...НО предположим,что вы изменчивы в настроении и уже у вас `А вызывает OnTriggerEnter и получает collider объекта B. Так вот у меня есть объект B и из него я вызываю свой скрипт.` - что мешает написать `collider.gameObject.GetComponent<YOUR_COMPONENT>();`? Но скорее вам надо постараться формулировать вопрос правильно. Возможно с визуализацией

Comment: Да ты издеваешься ? **A** и **B** это был пример, в котором про **A**  ничего не известно, есть только **B** с коллайдером, **А** ничего не вызывает он где то там существует и может попасть в колайдер **В**, скрипт доожен вызываться из **В** и узнавать вошел ли в его коллайдер какой либо объект, в данном примере **А** зачем мне `collider.gameObject.GetComponent<YOUR_COMPONENT>` это будет то же что `collider.` **объект B** `.GetComponent<Зачем мне этот компонент` если мне нужен объект A

Comment: @CGLike тяжело.....`А вызывает OnTriggerEnter и получает collider объекта B` а теперь пишите `А ничего не вызывает он где то там существует` - вы бы определись что у вас где расположено, что куда попадает, что где навешано и что хотите получить. Я же говорю, у вас проблемы с правильным формулированием мыслей. Окей. Давайте пойдем по варианту, описанному вами выше... **B** и с коллайдером и со скриптом. Должен определить кто в него вошел. Например **A**. Решение: для этого объекту **B** добавляем еще коллайдер и жмём на нем галочку `Is Trigger` и пользуемся ответом....сюрприз.....из ответа выше

Comment: `A вызывает` это был примерная последовательность что бы сказать о том что мне нужно из B его найти(А), потому что ни кто в комментах с самого начала этого так и не понял, и на этом основывались мои ответы. Написано же - _А как получить сам объект(_ **A** _), который вошел в_ **B.** _collider из самого объекта с триггером(_ **B** _)._ там же упомянул что триггер и колайдер в моем случае одно и тоже.
Так же выше в комментах я написал `В общем я узнал про OverlapSphere, и видимо это то что нужно.`

Comment: @CGLike `там же упомянул что триггер и колайдер в моем случае одно и тоже.` - где? черт подери, где?........если объект **B** имеет триггер, как вы говорите, и скрипт и из него нужно получить объект **А**, то в чем вообще проблема? Уже миллион раз сказали как это сделать, а вы только кричите, что это неправильно...........и в чем же отличается `OverlapSphere`, который возвращает **массив коллайдеров** которые **прикасаются** или **находятся** внутри сферы, но **не** входят в нее.......`OnTriggerEnter` возвращает коллайдер объекта, входящего в  триггер, в котором лежит тот самый вошедший объект

Comment: В спойлере `триггер это тот же collider`. [Вот](https://vk.com/doc96944401_439350880?hash=dce12d7285dd6d8143&dl=24a09370e133b98860) пример попробуй написать OnTriggerEnter из B что бы получить А.

Comment: Надеюсь понятно где что